# iOS 9 UIWebView get html document width and height

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios9

in iOS8, I set webView origin size is (1,1). I use webView.scrollView.contentSize to get the html width and height(html meta width=device-width), then fit the webView size. it works well.
But in iOS9, I rebuild the app with xcode 7. And I get the webView contentSize is wrong(width is less than device width). so is it a UIWebView bug in iOS9?

Comment: "so is it a UIWebView bug in iOS9?" More likely a bug in your code. Content size of a web view comes from the HTML it is displaying. You should have no reason to mess with it manually.

Comment: I resize the webView frame size. not content size. cause I want to snapshot the webView.

Comment: Well, you're not showing _any_ code. So no one has any idea what you're doing. How do we know you've even waited until the content is fully loaded?

Comment: I write code below, the javascript will call doLoad

Comment: the webView can show all the html page, but the width is less than device width and the height is too height than what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

## define ORIGIN_FRAME CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 1)

- (UIWebView *)snapshotWebView {
  if (!_snapshotWebView) {
      _snapshotWebView = [[MTXWebView alloc] initWithManager:self frame:ORIGIN_FRAME];
      _snapshotWebView.webViewDelegate = self;
  }
  return _snapshotWebView;
  }
- (void)webview:(MTXWebView *)webView doLoad:(NSDictionary *)data callback:(WVJBResponseCallback)responseCallback {
  webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
  UIImage *image = [_snapshotWebView renderToImage];
  self.completionBlock(image);
  self.snapshotWebView.frame = ORIGIN_FRAME;
  }